# Don't have reinstall option on live CD

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, live-cd

I want to reinstall my [Ubuntu 14.04.2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ubuntu_releases#Ubuntu_14.04_LTS_.28Trusty_Tahr.29) (Trusty Tahr), but the option **reinstall without loosing data** or something like that don't show to me. This is what I get: *errase ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS and reinstall*

Here a image with the Ubuntu live CD:

[image]

Then if I choose *something else* (in the installations options), I get my partitioning list like like this

[image]

but I can't decide what partition to format so I don't know what to do for reinstalling my Ubuntu without losing my installed programs. My `/home` directories are backuped.

Answer (score 0):

Much of the point of re-installing, is that something has gone wrong - so if it kept all your installed programs, it would do nothing. It will however keep your home directory, so you shouldn't lose data - or at least try to..

apt-get does have the facility to do this, package by package: `man apt-get`:

> --reinstall   Re-install packages that are already installed and at the newest version.

so you could re-install a broken package, or a few, without a whole start from scratch.

Comment: I ran  `sudo apt -get  --reinstall`  and nothing  happends.  Im not an advanced  user i can say.

Comment: If you  see  my only other question im  having  problems with my boot since i uninstall gnome -shell

Comment: I think you need to run the install! It's not that hard to re-install a bunch of programs, but if you've taken out half the display manager it's just not worthwhile to try & find out what's gone.. Just do it! You should find your /home stuff is intact, but good that you have a backup already.

Answer (score 0):

First of all [take a full system backup](https://askubuntu.com/questions/569679/whats-a-good-back-up-strategy-for-1-desktop-pc) before continuing. (you've been upgraded to user type 4)

As you've kept your `/home` separate from your `/`, you need to choose the `/dev/mapper/VG1-LVroot` and check the "format" check mark in your second screen shot.  Then your system will be erased, while your data and configuration settings will be kept.

If however, your problem is not gone afterwards, you should create an additional user and just copy your data directories (`Pictures`, `Documents`, ...) over to the new user and leave all other files where they are and then delete the original user, removing it's home directory.